# Optimize postgres function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, optimization

Function code. Its works very slowly. How can I speed up

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bill."ReportIngredients"(
    _from date,
    _to date,
    _beginning_date date,
    _has_inventory boolean,
    _inventory_id uuid,
    _restaurant_id uuid,
    _stock_id uuid,
    _ingredientIds uuid [],
    _sort_by character varying,
    _limit integer,
    _offset integer

  )
  RETURNS TABLE(
    json json
  ) AS
$BODY$
declare
  ingredientFilter character varying = '';
  ingredient_id uuid;
  ss_date date;
begin
  if ( _ingredientIds is not null ) then
    ingredientFilter = 'and i.id IN (';
    FOREACH ingredient_id in array _ingredientIds loop
      ingredientFilter := ingredientFilter || '''' ||  ingredient_id ||  ''',';
    end loop;
    Select trim(trailing ',' from ingredientFilter) into ingredientFilter;
    ingredientFilter := ingredientFilter || ') ';
  end if;

  if ( _has_inventory ) then
  return query execute
    'select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
      From (
        Select i.id, i.title,
          (
            (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(ii.delta_count), 0)
              FROM inventory_ingredients ii
              Inner Join inventories inven On inven.id = ii.inventory_id
              WHERE ii.ingredient_id = i.id
                And inven.is_active = true
                And inven.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And inven.id = ''' || _inventory_id || '''
            ) + (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(ii.count), 0)
              FROM invoice_ingredients ii
              Inner Join invoices invo On invo.id = ii.invoice_id
              WHERE ii.is_active = true
                And ii.ingredient_id = i.id
                And invo.is_active = true
                And invo.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                And invo.receiver_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And invo.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                And invo.date < ''' || _from || '''
            ) + (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
              FROM relocation_ingredients ri
              Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
              WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
                And r.is_active = true
                And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                And r.receiver_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And r.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                And r.date < ''' || _from || '''
            ) - (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(wi.count), 0)
              FROM write_off_ingredients wi
              Inner Join write_offs w On w.id = wi.write_off_id
              WHERE wi.ingredient_id = i.id
                And w.is_active = true
                And w.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And w.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                And w.date < ''' || _from || '''
            ) - (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
              FROM relocation_ingredients ri
              Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
              WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
                And r.is_active = true
                And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                And r.sender_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And r.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                And r.date < ''' || _from || '''
            ) - (
                Select ((
                  SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                  FROM bill_calculations bc
                  Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bc.object_id
                  Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                  WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                    And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                    And bc.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                    And bc.date < ''' || _from || '''
                    And bc.calculate_type = ''subtract''
                    And b.bill_type <> 5
                )  - (
                  SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                  FROM bill_calculations bc
                  Inner Join bill.bill_course_resigns bcr on bcr.id = bc.object_id
                  Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bcr.bill_course_sold_id
                  Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                  WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                    And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                    And bc.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                    And bc.date < ''' || _from || '''
                    And bc.calculate_type = ''add''
                    And b.bill_type <> 5
                )) AS sum
            )
          ) AS start_count,
          (
            SELECT coalesce(sum(ii.count), 0)
            FROM invoice_ingredients ii
            Inner Join invoices invo On invo.id = ii.invoice_id
            WHERE ii.is_active = true
              And ii.ingredient_id = i.id
              And invo.is_active = true
              And invo.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
              And invo.receiver_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
              And invo.date >= ''' || _from || '''
              And invo.date <= ''' || _to || '''
          ) AS invoice_count,
          (
            SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
            FROM relocation_ingredients ri
            Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
            WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
              And r.is_active = true
              And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
              And r.receiver_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
              And r.date >= ''' || _from || '''
              And r.date <= ''' || _to || '''
          ) AS relocation_in_count,

          (
            SELECT coalesce(sum(wi.count), 0)
            FROM write_off_ingredients wi
            Inner Join write_offs w On w.id = wi.write_off_id
            WHERE wi.ingredient_id = i.id
              And w.is_active = true
              And w.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
              And w.date >= ''' || _from || '''
              And w.date <= ''' || _to || '''
          ) AS write_off_count,
          (
            SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
            FROM relocation_ingredients ri
            Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
            WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
              And r.is_active = true
              And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
              And r.sender_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
              And r.date >= ''' || _from || '''
              And r.date <= ''' || _to || '''
          ) AS relocation_out_count,
          (
              Select ((
                SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                FROM bill_calculations bc
                Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bc.object_id
                Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                  And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                  And bc.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                  And bc.date <= ''' || _to || '''
                  And bc.calculate_type = ''subtract''
                  And b.bill_type <> 5
              )  - (
                SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                FROM bill_calculations bc
                Inner Join bill.bill_course_resigns bcr on bcr.id = bc.object_id
                Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bcr.bill_course_sold_id
                Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                  And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                  And bc.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                  And bc.date <= ''' || _to || '''
                  And bc.calculate_type = ''add''
                  And b.bill_type <> 5
              )) AS sum
          ) AS solds_count,
          (
            SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
            FROM bill_calculations bc
            Inner Join bill.bill_course_resigns bcr on bcr.id = bc.object_id
            Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bcr.bill_course_sold_id
            Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
            WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
              And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
              And bc.date >= ''' || _from || '''
              And bc.date <= ''' || _to || '''
              And bc.calculate_type = ''add''
              And b.bill_type <> 5
          ) AS resign_count
        From ingredients i
        Where i.is_active = true
          And i.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
          ' || ingredientFilter || '
        Group by i.id
        order by ' || _sort_by || '
        limit ' || _limit || '
        offset ' || _offset || '
    ) t';
  else
    return query execute
      'select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
        From (
          Select i.id, i.title,
            (
              (
                SELECT coalesce(sum(ii.count), 0)
                FROM invoice_ingredients ii
                Inner Join invoices invo On invo.id = ii.invoice_id
                WHERE ii.is_active = true
                  And ii.ingredient_id = i.id
                  And invo.is_active = true
                  And invo.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                  And invo.receiver_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                  And invo.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                  And invo.date < ''' || _from || '''
              ) + (
                SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
                FROM relocation_ingredients ri
                Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
                WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
                  And r.is_active = true
                  And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                  And r.receiver_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                  And r.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                  And r.date < ''' || _from || '''
              ) - (
                SELECT coalesce(sum(wi.count), 0)
                FROM write_off_ingredients wi
                Inner Join write_offs w On w.id = wi.write_off_id
                WHERE wi.ingredient_id = i.id
                  And w.is_active = true
                  And w.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                  And w.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                  And w.date < ''' || _from || '''
              ) - (
                SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
                FROM relocation_ingredients ri
                Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
                WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
                  And r.is_active = true
                  And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                  And r.sender_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                  And r.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                  And r.date < ''' || _from || '''
              ) - (
                  Select ((
                    SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                    FROM bill_calculations bc
                    Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bc.object_id
                    Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                    WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                      And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                      And bc.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                      And bc.date < ''' || _from || '''
                      And bc.calculate_type = ''subtract''
                      And b.bill_type <> 5
                  )  - (
                    SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                    FROM bill_calculations bc
                    Inner Join bill.bill_course_resigns bcr on bcr.id = bc.object_id
                    Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bcr.bill_course_sold_id
                    Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                    WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                      And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                      And bc.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
                      And bc.date < ''' || _from || '''
                      And bc.calculate_type = ''add''
                      And b.bill_type <> 5
                  )) AS sum
              )
            ) AS start_count,
            (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(ii.count), 0)
              FROM invoice_ingredients ii
              Inner Join invoices invo On invo.id = ii.invoice_id
              WHERE ii.is_active = true
                And ii.ingredient_id = i.id
                And invo.is_active = true
                And invo.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                And invo.receiver_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And invo.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                And invo.date <= ''' || _to || '''
            ) AS invoice_count,
            (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
              FROM relocation_ingredients ri
              Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
              WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
                And r.is_active = true
                And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                And r.receiver_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And r.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                And r.date <= ''' || _to || '''
            ) AS relocation_in_count,
            (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(wi.count), 0)
              FROM write_off_ingredients wi
              Inner Join write_offs w On w.id = wi.write_off_id
              WHERE wi.ingredient_id = i.id
                And w.is_active = true
                And w.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And w.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                And w.date <= ''' || _to || '''
            ) AS write_off_count,
            (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(ri.count), 0)
              FROM relocation_ingredients ri
              Inner Join relocations r On r.id = ri.relocation_id
              WHERE ri.ingredient_id = i.id
                And r.is_active = true
                And r.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
                And r.sender_stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And r.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                And r.date <= ''' || _to || '''
            ) AS relocation_out_count,
            (
                Select ((
                  SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                  FROM bill_calculations bc
                  Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bc.object_id
                  Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                  WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                    And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                    And bc.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                    And bc.date <= ''' || _to || '''
                    And bc.calculate_type = ''subtract''
                    And b.bill_type <> 5
                )  - (
                  SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
                  FROM bill_calculations bc
                  Inner Join bill.bill_course_resigns bcr on bcr.id = bc.object_id
                  Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bcr.bill_course_sold_id
                  Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
                  WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                    And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                    And bc.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                    And bc.date <= ''' || _to || '''
                    And bc.calculate_type = ''add''
                    And b.bill_type <> 5
                )) AS sum
            ) AS solds_count,
            (
              SELECT coalesce(sum(bc.count), 0)
              FROM bill_calculations bc
              Inner Join bill.bill_course_resigns bcr on bcr.id = bc.object_id
              Inner Join bill.bill_course_solds bcs on bcs.id = bcr.bill_course_sold_id
              Inner Join bill.bills b on b.id = bcs.bill_id
              WHERE bc.ingredient_id = i.id
                And bc.stock_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
                And bc.date >= ''' || _from || '''
                And bc.date <= ''' || _to || '''
                And bc.calculate_type = ''add''
                And b.bill_type <> 5
            ) AS resign_count
          From ingredients i
          Where i.is_active = true
            And i.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
            ' || ingredientFilter || '
          Group by i.id
          order by ' || _sort_by || '
          limit ' || _limit || '
          offset ' || _offset || '
      ) t';
    end if;
end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 50
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION bill."ReportIngredients"(date, date, date, boolean, uuid, uuid, uuid, uuid[], character varying, integer, integer)
  OWNER TO developer;
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE   result

```
"Result  (cost=0.00..5.13 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=38859.253..38859.254 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 38859.296 ms"
```

Comment: First - try rewriting the sub queries into one big query. You are scanning same tables multiple times. Second - `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the sub queries and look for possible indexes.

Comment: SO is not for reviewing big chunks of bad code. You might try codereview.stackexchange.com or just do the work yourself. Come back with a clearly defined question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You've got around 14 subqueries in there, any one of which could be responsible for 90% of the execution time due to a missing index or bad statistics, and each one seems to be executed for every ingredient projected from the ingredients table query. So if there are 50 ingredients then each execution of a subquery might on average take 40ms -- does that sound unreasonable?

I'd suggest that you get the actual SQL executed and look to see if the subqueries are indeed executed that many times. If so, try to restructure the query as a set of common table expressions, starting with the selection of the ingredients, and with one CTE per subquery in which you join to the ingredient list and aggregate to the ingredient level. Join the CTE's together in the final part of the query.

what you'll end up with would be something like:

```
with
  cte_ingredients as (
    select id,
           title
    from   ingredients
    where  ...),
  cte_invoice_ingredients as (
    SELECT i.id,
           sum(ii.count) amt
    FROM cte_ingredients i join
         invoice_ingredients ii on ii.ingredient_id = i.id
          Inner Join invoices invo On invo.id = ii.invoice_id
   WHERE ii.is_active = true
         And invo.is_active = true
         And invo.restaurant_id = ''' || _restaurant_id || '''
         And invo.receiver_id = ''' || _stock_id || '''
         And invo.date >= ''' || _beginning_date || '''
         And invo.date < ''' || _from || '''
   group by i.id),
   ... rest of the CTE's ...
select i.id,
       i.title,
       coalesce(ii.amt,0) ii_amt,
       ... blah blah arithmetic ..
from cte_ingredients i left join
     cte_invoice_ingredients ii on i.id = ii.id
```